# Redis Unexpected reply to PSYNC from master: -NOAUTH Authentication required

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, redis, redis-cluster

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  network_ext:
    external: true

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    hostname: redis
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    networks:
      - network_ext
    command: --slaveof host.dev.k8s.net 30916--slave-announce-ip 127.0.0.1
    environment:
      - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=slave
      - REDIS_MASTER_HOST=host.dev.k8s.net 
      - REDIS_MASTER_PORT_NUMBER=30916
      - REDIS_MASTER_PASSWORD=master-pwd
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=redis-pwd
```

I already have a redis master cluster in `k8s` available of the host `host.dev.k8s.net` with port `6379` with pwd `master-pwd`.

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
c5fa13ec5a90   redis:latest             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 seconds ago    Up 2 seconds    0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp   service_redis_1
```

I try to create a slave in a docker container. But i receive these error:

```
docker logs -f c5fa13ec5a90
1:C 03 Aug 2023 14:20:47.603 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 03 Aug 2023 14:20:47.603 # Redis version=7.0.12, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 03 Aug 2023 14:20:47.603 # Configuration loaded
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:47.603 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:47.604 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:47.604 # Server initialized
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:47.604 # WARNING Memory overcommit must be enabled! Without it, a background save or replication may fail under low memory condition. Being disabled, it can can also cause failures without low memory condition, see https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/1328. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:47.604 * Ready to accept connections
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:47.605 * Connecting to MASTER host.dev.k8s.net:30916
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:48.062 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:48.517 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:48.972 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:49.410 * (Non critical) Master does not understand REPLCONF listening-port: -NOAUTH Authentication required.
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:49.410 * (Non critical) Master does not understand REPLCONF ip-address: -NOAUTH Authentication required.
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:49.410 * (Non critical) Master does not understand REPLCONF capa: -NOAUTH Authentication required.
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:49.410 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:49.877 # Unexpected reply to PSYNC from master: -NOAUTH Authentication required.
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:49.877 * Retrying with SYNC...
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:50.327 # MASTER aborted replication with an error: NOAUTH Authentication required.
1:S 03 Aug 2023 14:20:50.327 * Reconnecting to MASTER host.dev.k8s.net:30916 after failure
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the command im yml

```
command: redis-server --slaveof host.dev.k8s.net 30916 --masterauth master-pwd --slave-announce-ip 127.0.0.1
```